# Variable substitution not working in $in in mongo with node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have constructed the node path as `/57639afa5961debc1b256745/, /5763c5d17d05688c1838c7a3/,` but when I try to subtitute with `nodepath` it gets the result as empty array even though it has the children:

```
Degree.prototype.findByPath = function(dbObj, degrees) {
    var nodePath = '';

    for(var i in degrees) {
        nodePath = nodePath + '/' + degrees[i]['_id'] + '/, ';
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log(nodePath);
        dbObj.collection('degree').find({ 
            'path': {
                '$in': 
                    [ nodePath ] 
                } 
            }).toArray((err, results) => {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    var nodes;

                    if(results != null)
                        nodes = degrees.concat(results);
                    else
                        nodes = degrees;

                    resolve(nodes);
                }               
            });
    }); 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build up `nodePath` as an array of strings rather than one comma-separated string. And if you want the id values treated as regular expressions, use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor instead of adding slash characters:

```
var nodePath = [];

for(var i in degrees) {
    nodePath.push(new RegExp(degrees[i]['_id']));
}

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log(nodePath);
    dbObj.collection('degree').find({ 
        'path': {
            '$in': nodePath
            } 
        }).toArray((err, results) => {...
```

Comment: Degree.prototype.findByPath = function(dbObj, degrees) {
    var nodePath = '';

    for(var i in degrees) {
        nodePath = nodePath + degrees[i]['_id'] + ', ';
    }

    if(nodePath != '') 
          nodePath = '[' +nodePath + ']';

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log(nodePath);
        dbObj.collection('degree').find({ 
            'path': {
                '$regex': nodePath
                } 
            }).toArray((err, results) => {

Comment: @Sethu Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: your code not worked as expected.

So i try with $regex it works as expected.